# Separate items in the url

Tags: url-routing

First, I don't know if this is stupid question but I Will explain to you my problem.

I have a URL, is like this `domain/make/model`, for example `http://www.domain.com/bmw/z3`, I would like join the make & model in the url, like http://www.domain.com/bmw:z3/ or http://www.domain.com/bmw#z3/, but I can not use this ":" char because the server thinks is an hack attack, I would like to know, which  char you recommend to me to separate items in the URL, I can not use "-", maybe the make and model have this char...

Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with `/`?

Comment: Nothing, but the company wants separate the items with another char.